# Netlify & Faunadb Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, netlify, aws-serverless, faunadb

I get the following error only in production mode calling a Netlify AWS serverless function

ERROR  FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/faunadb failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
at ClientRequest. (/var/task/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1461:11)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:314:20)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:427:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
type: 'system',
errno: 'ECONNRESET',
code: 'ECONNRESET'
}

Here is the code:

```
const faunadb = require('faunadb');
q = faunadb.query;
var fauna_client = new faunadb.Client({ secret: '[..]' });

const redirect_uri = "/.netlify/functions/follow_spotify_callback";
const client_id = "[..]";
const client_secret = "[..]";
const basic =  Buffer.from(client_id + ":" + client_secret).toString('base64');

const qs = require('querystring');
const axios = require('axios');

exports.handler = async function(event, context) {

    const state = JSON.parse(event.queryStringParameters.state)


    axios.post(
        'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        qs.stringify({
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': event.queryStringParameters.code,
            'redirect_uri': process.env.URL + redirect_uri
        }),
        {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Basic ${basic}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }
    ).then(res => {
        const access_token = res.data.access_token;
        const headers = {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${res.data.access_token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        axios.get(
            "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me",
            {
                headers: headers,
            }
        ).then(result => {

            fauna_client.query(
                q.Exists(
                    q.Match(
                        q.Index('users_by_id'),
                        result.data.id
                    )
                )
            ).then(ret => {
                if (ret == false){
                    fauna_client.query(
                        q.Create(
                            q.Collection('users'),
                            { data: { 
                                display_name: result.data.display_name,
                                id: result.data.id,
                                access_token: access_token,
                                campaign: state.artisturi,
                                playlist: state.playlisturi,
                                referred_by: state.referrer
                            } }
                        )
                    )
                }else{
                    console.log("user already exists")
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
        ).catch(err =>{
            console.log(err.message)
        });
        axios.put('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/following?type=artist', {
            'ids': [state.artisturi],
        }, {
            headers: headers
        });
        axios.put(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${state.playlisturi}/followers`, {
            'public': true,
        }, {
            headers: headers,
        });
        axios.put('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks', {
            'ids': [state.trackuri],
        }, {
            headers: headers,
        })
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err.message)
    })

    return{
        statusCode: 302,
        headers: {
            Location: 'https://open.spotify.com/playlist/'+state.playlisturi
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works locally running `netlify dev`, but not in production mode, and it is on https with SSL / TLS encryption

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running into the problem described here: https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/drivers/known_issues

If you move the code that instantiates a Fauna client into your handler logic, the problem might go away.